# Get the latest two objects from parse based on the field createdAt in ios

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have multiple objects with the same valued in the "name" Column.i want to get the latest two objects that have been created in parse.
For example

```
 COlUMNNAME           COLUMNNAME2     CREATEDAT
 THIS IS A STRING          0          2015-05-25T08:16:03.672Z
 THIS IS A STRING          1          2015-04-25T08:16:03.672Z
 THIS IS A STRING          1          2015-03-25T08:16:03.672Z
```

The query should return the first two rows.Is there a way to do that in parse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the query constraints where you can order based on createdAt feature. Following that via using the query limit options you can set a number that you want Parse to return(such as query.limit(2)). Hope this helps.

Regards.